# Rails 3; add an 'and' to a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following query that returns all registrations where the orientation is nil...

```
@registrations = Registration.includes(:orientation).
                  where(orientations: {:class_date => nil})
```

I need to add a 2nd filter so I only a particular last name, so something like...

```
@registrations = Registration.includes(:orientation).
                  where(orientations: {:class_date => nil AND :last_name => "smith"})
```

However, this syntax is incorrect. How can I add a 'AND' or && statement to the end of this where clause?

Comment: Never used ruby-on-rails but at a guess, where(orientations: {:class_date => nil}) AND (orientations:{last_name => "smith"}) ?

Comment: No cigar @OTTA. Rails no likey: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All key/value pairs are joined in a `where()` with `AND`:

```
Registration.includes(:orientation).
  where(orientations: {:class_date => nil}, :last_name => "smith")
```

Comment: Just remove the `}`: `{:class_date => nil, :last_name => "smith"}`

Comment: remove it from the first condition :)

Comment: @user2503775 No, you wouldn't do that. The OP has `include`ed the orientations relation, so the WHERE part of the query would be `WHERE (orientations.class_date) IS NULL AND registrations.last_name = 'smith'`. The nested hash indicates that k/v pair is for another table (organizations) that is `JOIN`ed on the query.